# How do I send a Pardot Prospect an email every time a specific Prospect field changes?

Tags: email, automation, form, pardot

Say we have a Pardot Prospect field 'Interests' and someone would update that field, either they themselves using a form or we do it through the Pardot UI (if we're on the phone with them).

Then how can I send out an email saying 'Thanks for updating your interests' every time they/we change that field?

I can use an automation rule, but that only matches once. So that does not cover the case when we update the field multiple times.

I can create a completion action on a form (which runs on every submit), but that doesn't cover the usecase that I change the 'Interests' field through the UI or the API etc.

Any other options?

Comment: Hi Willem did you find a solution already?

Comment: No not really, unfortunately. We've started to look into other soloutions as well, because it seems to be too difficult in Pardot at this time.

Comment: Good news I guess, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pardot: June 29, 2017

> Pardot Automation Rules now have ‘repeat’ functionality. This new
>   feature allows the User to determine if an Automation Rule should be
>   allowed to match a prospect more than once.

Source: [Pardot blog | Automation Rule Repeat Functionality](https://www.pardot.com/blog/automation-rules-now-repeat-rule-functionality/)

Comment: That's *exactly* what I needed! Thanks so much for sharing!